# need to add some compression code to .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, shopify

I have one shopify site ,To increase my site speed i need to make some improvement in "caching" and "compression" section

For that i have some code that i need to add in .ht-access page

here is my code

```
       Header unset Pragma
       FileETag None
       Header unset ETag


       ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
       <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive On
     ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
     ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
     ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
     ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
     ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
     ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
     ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
     ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
     ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
     ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
     ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
     </IfModule>
     ## EXPIRES CACHING ##



     <FilesMatch "\\.(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
     SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </FilesMatch>



    <IfModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
   </IfModule>
```

How this can be done . if not really possible what is the solution ?

Can any one help on this ?

Comment: "i need to add in .ht-access page" - FWIW, it would probably be `.htaccess`, not `.ht-access` (if Shopify supports per-directory Apache config files).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Shopify doesn't give you access to .htaccess file. Nevertheless, Shopify does an amazing job with the resources. Unless you are frequently changing theme files or adding new files to the files sections, Shopify's version caching is one of the best.